# В каких словах первый звук звонкий, а в каких глухой?

Tags: фонетика, согласные

В каких словах первый звук звонкий, а в каких глухой?

```
Шапка
Санки
Бак
Флаги
Круг
Луч
Хлеб
Глаз
Нос
Звук
Волк
Рот
Крыса
Парта
```

**Обновление**

Звонкие - бак, луч, глаз, нос, звук, волк, рот.  
Глухие - шапка, санки, флаг, круг, хлеб, крыса, парта?

Answer (score 0):

Все **правильно**. В словах `луч, нос, рот, хлеб` - 
**без** вопросов, так как они начинаются с непарного звука.

Все остальные **можно** проверить подобрав произношение с **парой** первого звука. Если ощущается **сильная** разница, то всё **правильно**.

*Пример*: "**ф**лаг-**в**лаг", есть разница в **звучании**? **Да**, флаг начинается с **глухого**.

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, отметьте галочкой (слева от ответа).